# Is there a good way to allow setting of assert.expect(n) in multiple places?

Tags: javascript, qunit

I'm writing tests for a non-trivial API and many things need to be repeated for different tests. I've split out common stuff in separate functions, but Unfortunately, this makes it a huge pain to use `assert.expect(n)` in any meaningful way. Is there any way that I can improve this? I've been looking for something that will let me do `expect`s for the current function only:

```
function x(assert) {
    assert.expect(2);
    y(assert);
    // 2 asserts.
    assert.testExpects();
}

function y(assert) {
    assert.expect(1);
    // Assert.
    assert.testExpects();
}
```

Or some way to increment the expected number of asserts. Something like this:

```
function x(assert) {
    assert.expect(assert.expected + 2);
    y(assert);
    // 2 asserts.
}

function y(assert) {
    assert.expect(assert.expected + 1);
    // Assert.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, even though it's not written in the [documentation](http://api.qunitjs.com/expect/), it appears that `assert.expect()` (without parameters) returns the current number of expected asserts, which could be used like in the second example in the OP. I only found out by going through the source code though, so I'm not sure whether this is a feature that will continue to work in the future, but it'll work for now unless someone has a better solution.